# Group by and keep columns with matching pattern

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm trying to figure out how to group by one variable and keep all other variables that have the same variation pattern. Here's a sample df where gp is my grouping variable:

```
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 gp
1  0  1  0  0  0  0  x
2  0  0  0  0  1  0  x
3  1  0  1  0  1  1  y
4  0  0  0  0  0  1  x
```

What I'd like to end up with is:

```
  V1 V3 gp
1  0  0  x
2  0  0  x
3  1  1  y
4  0  0  x
```

I've tried a bunch of things, but nothing that get's me anywhere close to something useful. My real data will be much larger, but I figure this is a good place to start. In this case, I could do something numeric, but my 'real data' are genomic data, and thus not as easily added as 0s and 1s.

data:

```
structure(list(V1 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), V2 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    V3 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), V4 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V5 = c(0L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L), V6 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), gp = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("x", "y"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: For the 'y' group, there are more than one column having 1

Comment: I know that, but I want the pattern to be the same (ie 0010 to match xxyx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by finding columns that have a bijection from `gp` to the values for that column. That is, for every value in `gp` (`x` or `y`) there is exactly one matching value in the variable column e.g. `V1` (`0` or `1`). The reverse is also true, for every value in a variable column like `V1` there is exactly one match in `gp`.

To operate on all columns at once, start by pivoting to a longer form. This will also remove the easy duplicates right away.

```
uniq <- df %>% pivot_longer(-gp) %>% distinct(name, gp, value)
#    name  gp    value
#    <chr> <fct> <int>
#  1 V1    x         0
#  2 V2    x         1
#  3 V3    x         0
#  4 V4    x         0
#  5 V5    x         0
#  6 V6    x         0
#  7 V2    x         0
#  8 V5    x         1
# ...
# 14 V6    y         1
# 15 V6    x         1
```

Then you can find the "exactly once" matches in one direction by counting how often each `gp` value shows up per `name`. It will be exactly once if it always matches a constant value for the variable column.

```
match_left <- uniq %>%
  count(name, gp) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  filter(max(n) == 1) %>%
  distinct(name)

match_left
# # A tibble: 3 x 1
# # Groups:   name [3]
#   name 
#   <chr>
# 1 V1   
# 2 V3   
# 3 V4
```

Do the same thing, but in reverse for the value column.

```
match_right <- uniq %>%
  count(name, value) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  filter(max(n) == 1) %>%
  distinct(name)

match_right
# # A tibble: 2 x 1
# # Groups:   name [2]
#   name 
#   <chr>
# 1 V1   
# 2 V3
```

Now that we know which variables to keep, we can merge everything back together and reshape to the wide form.

```
matches <- df %>%
  mutate(i = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(i, gp)) %>%
  inner_join(match_left, on='name') %>%
  inner_join(match_right, on='name') %>%
  spread(name, value) %>%
  arrange(i) %>%
  select(-i)

matches
# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#   gp       V1    V3
#   <fct> <int> <int>
# 1 x         0     0
# 2 x         0     0
# 3 y         1     1
# 4 x         0     0
```

Comment: Awesome, this works great. A bit lengthy, but gets the job done. I wasn't quite thinking through all of the potential steps and was getting stuck after the pivot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `duplicated` to get columns that are repeated. However, `duplicated` works in row-wise fashion so we transpose the original dataframe.

```
t1 <- t(df[-ncol(df)])
df[c(duplicated(t1) | duplicated(t1, fromLast = TRUE), TRUE)]

#  V1 V3 gp
#1  0  0  x
#2  0  0  x
#3  1  1  y
#4  0  0  x
```

The final `TRUE` is to select the last column which is `gp`.

Comment: So this works on the exact example I gave, but not so well on my real data, as there are some duplicated columns that aren't of interest.